# How to show alert controller after getting response from api in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have a method that posts `HTTP` data, After getting the response from `API` I want to display an `UIAlertController` on the basis of status codes.

Suppose the status code I got is **409**, So the controller will say **"data already exists"**.

How to present `alert controller` and in which class, service class or any other `view controller`?

**ViewController.h**

```
- (IBAction)logIn:(id)sender {

    if (username.text == nil || [password.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:
                                    @"all the fields are mendetary"
                                message:@"missing username or password " preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:@"OKAY" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *_Nonnull action)
                                 {
                                     //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                 }];
        [alert addAction:action];
       [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
   else
   {
        [[service SharedInstance] logIn:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:username.text,@"username",password.text,@"password",nil] params:@"logIn" block:^(const BOOL success, id resultObject, NSError *error )
        {


            // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Loggedin" sender:self];
         }];

    }

   username.text =@"";
    password.text =@"";


    }
```

**Service.m**

```
-(void)logIn:(NSDictionary *)Details params:(NSString *)params block:(ResponseBlock)block{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *URL = @"http://localhost:8080";
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
    NSString *requestURL = [URL stringByAppendingString:@"/api/signupUser"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]; NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120.0]; NSData *data = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    NSString *base64Encoded = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSLog(@"base64Encoded%@",base64Encoded);
    NSString *basicString = @"Basic";
    basicString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",basicString,base64Encoded];
    NSLog(@"basicString%@",basicString);
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:basicString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *bodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:Details options:0 error:&error];

    [request setHTTPBody:bodyData];NSURLSessionTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    long statusCode =[httpResponse statusCode];
    NSLog(@"response status code: %ld", statusCode);
f (error)
       {
           block(NO, response,error);
        }
    else
        {
           NSError *err = nil;
           id responseData = [NSJSONSerialization
           JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&err];
           NSDictionary* headers= [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
           NSLog(@"all header fields %@",headers);
           [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"userToken"];
           NSLog(@"token %@",[defaults valueForKey:@"userToken"]);
           NSDate *expireDate = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*25];
           [defaults setObject:expireDate forKey:@"sessionDate"];

            if(err)
            {
              block(NO, response, error);
            }
            else
            {
              block(YES, responseData,nil);
            }
              [task cancel];
        }
      }];
            [task resume];
        }
   @end
```

Comment: do not update your question in others answer just leave a comment here. what you want to do?

Comment: really sorry for that ,it was a mistake .

Comment: try my update answer.

Comment: Hey @learning_phase What is your issue? You just described the requirement in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are making some http call from a service file. There are few options here:

1. Implement delegate of your service class in ViewController to perform any task there.
2. Use blocks.
3. Use framework like Rx here.
4. or if you just need to display the alert add the alert to current window e.g.

I have created an extension for this purpose:

```
extension UIAlertController {
/// display alert with custom number of buttons
static func presentAlert(_ title: String?, message: String?, alertButtonTitles: [String], alertButtonStyles: [UIAlertActionStyle], vc: UIViewController, completion: @escaping (Int)->Void) -> Void
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
                                  message: message,
                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    for title in alertButtonTitles {
        let actionObj = UIAlertAction(title: title,
                                      style: alertButtonStyles[alertButtonTitles.index(of: title)!], handler: { action in
                                        completion(alertButtonTitles.index(of: action.title!)!)
        })
        alert.addAction(actionObj)
    }
    vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}
use:

```
UIAlertController.presentAlert("My Title", message: "My message", alertButtonTitles: "OK", alertButtonStyles: [.default], vc: (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController)!, completion: { (btnIndex) in

    })
```

Above code is adding UiAlerController over window.